# Python: Not all environment variables present in os.environ

Tags: python, environment

In the python shell, using

```
import os 
print os.environ
```

prints the complete list of environment variables with nothing missing. However when I call the interpreter with a filename:

```
sudo python file.py
```

and use

```
import os 
print os.environ
```

I see that some of the environment variables are missing in the dict.

Why do they behave differently?

Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you please paste the output from both ways?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "complete" environment. Different variables will be present in different situations.  What's missing, and why is it a problem?

Comment: They're identical for me!

Comment: which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: [`sudo -E`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

Comment: did you try using the `export` keyword e.g. `export DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"`?

Answer (score 4):

I saw this happen when ENV Vars were **not** set using **export** in bash, so they were not propagating to the python script.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that the difference was because I was using sudo during the execution for the second where the environment was not preserved. I need to add
those environment variables to my sudoers file or preserve them during execution.

Answer (score 1):

did you try using the `export` keyword e.g.

`export DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"`